# Resize and interpolate ndarray on specific axis

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Suppose I have 3-d numpy array like this:

```
arr = np.random.randn(14,10,10)
```

I need to resize it to shape of `(14, 20, 20)`. That means the first dimension is separately resized from `(10, 10)` to `(20, 20)` with interpolation method.

How could I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolate a 3D array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094020/interpolate-a-3d-array-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these sort of tasks a handy tool is [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html)

This will be `resizing` the array and interpolating it using [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation). In order to use it you need to provide a zooming factor, which in this case should be `[1,2,2]`. This will be specifying that you want a zooming factor of `2` along the two last axis:

```
from scipy.ndimage import interpolation

arr = np.random.randn(14,10,10)
new_arr = interpolation.zoom(arr,[1,2,2])

print(new_arr.shape)
# (14, 20, 20)
```

Comment: What if I need many arrays to be resized to same shape? adjust according to the zoom ratio might bring little shape difference between different arrays.

Comment: You mean many arrays with different shapes? This ratio works for the specific shape of the example you proposed. In order to compute the zooming factor of interest to get a specific shape you need `shape_of_interest / len(x)`, this will be your zooming factor for a given array

Comment: ou mean many arrays with different shapes? This ratio works for the specific shape of the example you proposed. In order to compute the zooming factor of interest to get a specific shape you need `shape_of_interest / shape_of_current_array`, this will be your zooming factor for a given array