# Extrapolate NaN values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, extrapolation

I have two values and know their index in an array full of nans. I want to interpolate / extrapolate all the nan's

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 0.75, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.25])
```

With the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6520696/7959614) I write the following:

```
nans, x = np.isnan(y), lambda z: z.nonzero()[0]
y[nans] = np.interp(x(nans), x(~nans), y[~nans])
```

My output looks as follows:

> [0.75 0.75 0.75 1.   1.25 1.5  1.75 2.   2.25]

However, I would like it to be:

> [0.25 0.5 0.75 1.   1.25 1.5  1.75 2.   2.25]

The increment is always a constant.
When I read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) of `np.iterp` I see that I can specify the input-parameters `left` and `right`. If I don't specify `left`, the value to return for *x < xp[0]* is *fp[0]*.

How can I specify `left` and `right` in order to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify `left` and `right` to achieve extrapolation with `interp`, they are just constant values.

If you prefer a pure numpy solution, you can linearly extrapolate based on the first/last two values of the interpolated array:

```
def extrap(x, xp, fp):
    m = (fp[1] - fp[0]) / (xp[1] - xp[0])
    n = fp[0] - m * xp[0]
    result = m * x[x < xp[0]] + n
    m = (fp[-1] - fp[-2]) / (xp[-1] - xp[-2])
    n = fp[-1] - m * xp[-1]
    return np.concatenate([result, m * x[x > xp[-1]] + n])
```

(you may want to add verification of `len(xp) > 1` and `len(xp) == len(yp)`)

Example:

```
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 0.75, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.25, np.nan])

nans, x = np.isnan(y), lambda z: z.nonzero()[0]
y[nans] = np.interp(x(nans), x(~nans), y[~nans], np.nan, np.nan)

nans, x = np.isnan(y), lambda z: z.nonzero()[0]
y[nans] = extrap(x(nans), x(~nans), y[~nans])
```

Result

```
array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  , 1.25, 1.5 , 1.75, 2.  , 2.25])
```

Answer (score 2):

[`np.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) doesn't seem to make extrapolation,
but [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) does.

The arguments to give are a bit different, you can make it a function for your particular case:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


def interp_nans(y, x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = np.arange(len(y))
    nans = np.isnan(y)

    interpolator = interp1d(
        x[~nans],
        y[~nans],
        kind="linear",
        fill_value="extrapolate",
        assume_sorted=True,
    )

    return interpolator(x)
```

Check that it works:

```py
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 0.75, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.25])
expected = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25])

result = interp_nans(y)

assert np.array_equal(result, expected)
```