# is it possible to combine a logical and a limit condition in a numpy array slice operator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have the following code that does exactly what I want, but it too slow, since it involves an unnecessary materialization step:

```
### init
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

### condition 1) element 0 has to be larger than 1
### condition 2) limit the output to 2 elements
b = a[a[:,0] > 1][:2]
```

The **problem** is that this is very slow when I have a big array(given that I only want to cut off a tiny piece with condition 2). It can easily be done, but I have not found a way of putting it into a one-liner.

Hence, is there a neat way of doing this efficiently in a **one-liner**? Something like this:

```
b = a[a[:,0] > 1 and :2]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should explain what the problem is, if it is the code itself or the math behind numpy.

Comment: this question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange I think ... but I dont think you can ...

Comment: So in effect, you want the operation to short circuit after `n` values have been found. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Why don't you simply reverse the order of the indexings? By doing `a[:, :2][a[:, 0] > 1]` you will not "materialize" the big array, but just one with the elements you are after.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, since you potentially have elements that you would remove in your 2nd step. I need ```n``` elements if there are ```n``` elements.

Comment: It seems unlikely that there's a super-clean way of doing this right now. In fact, a short-circuiting `find` for numpy doesn't yet exist; it's a feature request for the 2.0 release according to the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632963/numpy-array-how-to-find-index-of-first-occurrence-of-item). If they don't even have that, I'm not sure there's a good way of doing this without using vanilla python or coding your own extension.

Comment: @marco I see, I misunderstood you only wanted to keep the first two columns of every row, not just the first two rows...

Comment: @Jaime - You actually gave me an idea - I can take advantage of a slight twist in my setup. There are no more then ```n``` elements that I want to remove with *condition 1*. Hence I can do this: ```tmp_a = a[:n*2]; return tmp_a[tmp[:,0] > 1][:n]```. Since ```#a >> n``` this will give me a very nice speedup. But since I asked the question in a more generic manner this would not be the 100% correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a faster solution in straight numpy, but you can probably do a little better using `numba`:

```
from numba import autojit

def filtfunc(a):
    idx = []
    for ii in range(a.shape[0]):
        if (a[ii, 0] > 1):
            idx.append(ii)
            if (len(idx) == 2):
                break
    return a[idx]

jit_filter = autojit(filtfunc)
```

For reference, here are the other two proposed solutions:

```
def marco_filter(a):
    return a[a[:,0] > 1][:2]

def rico_filter(a):
    mask = a[:, 0] > 1
    where = np.where(mask)[0][:2]
    return a[where]
```

Some timings:

```
%%timeit a = np.random.random_integers(1, 12, (1000,1000))
marco_filter(a)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop

%%timeit a = np.random.random_integers(1, 12, (1000,1000))
rico_filter(a)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 44.8 µs per loop

%%timeit a = np.random.random_integers(1, 12, (1000,1000))
jit_filter(a)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 30.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to speed up this code a little, your current code works like this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

# Check your condition
mask = a[:, 0] > 1

# Copy those rows the array that satisfy the condition 
temp = a[mask]

# Take first two rows of temp
b = temp[:2]
```

I suspect the most expensive operation is the copy operation in the middle, you could try this to avoid it by doing something like:

```
mask = a[:, 0] > 1

# Find the first two True values in mask
where = np.where(mask)[0][:2]

# Only copy the rows you really want
b = a[where]
```

There may be a more efficient way to find the first two True values, I havn't given it that much thought but he key is to find the values you want first then to only copy those rows.

Comment: Yes, I have something similar, but was hoping for a more elegant way.

Comment: Hm, looking at ali_m's timings, this is an impressively effective solution!

Answer (score -2):

If `n=2` is quite small compared to `a.shape[0]`, it might be worth while using this little function.  The basic idea is calculate a mask that is just large enough to give the desired number of final rows.  Here I do it iteratively.  Normally iteration is slow, but if the number of iterations is small enough, the time saving elsewhere could be worth it.

```
def mask(a):
    return a[:,0]>1

def paul_filter1(a,n):
    # incremental w/ sum
    j = a.shape[0]
    for i in xrange(n,j+1):
        am = mask(a[:i,:])
        if np.sum(am)>=n:
            j = i
            break
    return a[am,:]
```

Note that the mask `am` can be shorter than the dimension it is working on.  Effectively it pads the rest with `False`.  I haven't checked if this is documented.

In this small example, `foo` is 3x slower than `a[a[:,0]>1,:][:2,:]`.

But with a larger array, say `a2=np.tile(a,[1000,1])`, the time with `foo` remains the same, but the 'brute force' keeps slowing down as it has to apply the mask to more rows.  Of course these timings do depend on where in `a` the desire rows are located.  There won't be any savings if `foo` has to use nearly all of the rows.

edit

Addressing Bi Rico's concerns about the repeated `np.sum` (even through that is fast compiled code), we could incrementally build the `where`:

```
def paul_filter3(a,n):
    # incremental adding index
    j = a.shape[0]
    am = mask(a[:n,:])
    am = np.where(am)[0].tolist()
    if len(am)<n:
        for i in xrange(n,j):
            if mask(a[[i],:]):
                am.append(i)
                if len(am)>=n:
                    break
    am = np.array(am)
    return a[am,:]
```

For small `n` this is even faster.

Something closer to the original method, is to calculate the full mask, but then trim it.  `cumsum` can be used to find the minimum length.

```
def paul_filter4(a,n):
    # cumsum
    am = mask(a)
    j = np.cumsum(am).searchsorted(n)
    return a[am[:j+1],:]
```

Tested with the `1000x1000` random array of integers (1:12), times are (using 20 instead of 2, and tweaking the mask so more rows are False

```
In [172]: timeit paul_filter4(a,20)
1000 loops, best of 3: 690 us per loop

In [173]: timeit paul_filter3(a,20)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop

In [175]: timeit paul_filter1(a,20)
1000 loops, best of 3: 994 us per loop

In [176]: timeit rico_filter(a,20)
1000 loops, best of 3: 668 us per loop

In [177]: timeit marco_filter(a,20)
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop
```

`rico_filter` using `where` is fastest, but my alternative using `cumsum` isn't far behind.  The 3 incremental filters are similar in speed, about half of the fast ones.

In this `a` as generated, and tested, most rows are `True`.  This is consistent with `marco's` concern that the limit condition is a small subset of the logical condition.  With these conditions Bi Rico's concern that `paul_filter1` could blow up is unrealistic.

If I change the testing parameters, so all of the rows of `a` have to be tested (`a[:,0]>11`),
then the filters using `where` and `cumsum` take just as long as the original.  The incremental filters are slower, by a factor of 15 or more.  But my first attempt using `np.sum` is fastest of that style.

Comment: While your basic idea is correct here, by using `am = am[:i, 0] > 1; if np.sum(am) == n ...` you've turned this into an O(N**2) approach. Even if n is small, this could blow up if `a[:, 0]` has a lot of small values. You could fix this by doing something similar to @ali_m's answer. The key is to avoid O(n) operations, like `sum`, inside your loop.

Comment: I've tried some alternative incremental functions that don't use the `sum` in the loop, and don't get any speed up.  `np.sum` is compiled code, so even if it is O(n) it doesn't slow down the loop.  Any incremental approach will be slow if it ends up testing most of the rows.