# OpenCV: fit the detected edges

Tags: python, opencv, curve-fitting, edge-detection

I detected the edges of a water wave by using canny edge detection. However, I want to fit a curve for this edge. Is that possible in OpenCV?

Here is the image before edge detection:
[image: Image before edge detection.]

Here is the result of the edge detection operation:
[image: Result after detecting]

The code was copied from an example in the OpenCV tutorials:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('BW.JPG',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)

plt.plot(1),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('WAVE')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wave is pretty simple, so we'll fit a polynomial curve to the primary edge defined by the output of `cv2`. First we want to get the points **of** that primary edge. Let's assume your origin is as it is on the image, at the top left. Looking at the original image, I think we'll have a good approximation for our points of interest if we just take the points with the largest `y` in the range (750, 1500).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numba import jit

# Show plot
img = cv2.imread('wave.jpg',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/29799815/1698058
# Get index of matching value.
@jit(nopython=True)
def find_first(item, vec):
    """return the index of the first occurence of item in vec"""
    for i in range(len(vec)):
        if item == vec[i]:
            return i
    return -1

bounds = [750, 1500]
# Now the points we want are the lowest-index 255 in each row
window = edges[bounds[1]:bounds[0]:-1].transpose()

xy = []
for i in range(len(window)):
    col = window[i]
    j = find_first(255, col)
    if j != -1:
        xy.extend((i, j))
# Reshape into [[x1, y1],...]
data = np.array(xy).reshape((-1, 2))
# Translate points back to original positions.
data[:, 1] = bounds[1] - data[:, 1]
```

If we graph these points, we can see they're very close to the ones we were aiming for.

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 16))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.axis([0, edges.shape[1], edges.shape[0], 0])
ax2.plot(data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image: extracted points]

And now that we've got an array of coordinate pairs we can use [`numpy.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to generate the coefficients for a best-fit polynomial, and [`numpy.poly1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) to generate the function from those coefficients.

```
xdata = data[:,0]
ydata = data[:,1]

z = np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 5)
f = np.poly1d(z)
```

and then plot to verify

```
t = np.arange(0, edges.shape[1], 1)
plt.figure(2, figsize=(8, 16))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.axis([0, edges.shape[1], edges.shape[0], 0])
ax2.plot(t, f(t))
plt.show()
```

[image: showing curve]

Comment: Wouldn't a trigonometric function be more natural for modeling a wave? The shape in manifestly sinusoidal.

Comment: I'll try it! My thinking was that a polynomial may work better here because it could fit the shallower areas on the far left and right more closely. Not that mine does, but filtering and/or discarding some points could produce a better result.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is all I want. Sorry that I saw this a little bit late. It works on my laptop, however I can't make it work on my Raspberry Pi 2 because I can't find a way to install 'numba'. Any suggestions?

Comment: No worries. `numba` was only required to make the `find_first` operation more efficient by compiling it prior to execution. You can just remove the import statement and the decorator `@jit(nopython=True)`. I just did a test, with `numba` it runs in ~80ms and without it runs in ~3.5s, which is significant but still reasonable depending on your application.