# Find element in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, time-complexity

Given a sorted array `A` and an element `x`, I need to find an algorithm that returns the index of `x` in `A` or `-1` if `x` is not in `A`.
the time complexity of the algorithm should be  `Θ(logd)` when d is the number of elements that appears before `x` in `A`, or if `x` is not in `A`, d is the number of elements that were before `x` if he was in `A`.

Binary search is not good enough because its best case is O(1).
I thought of starting from the beginning of the array, and start checking the indexes that are powers of 2. but I got lost.

Comment: Binary search worst case *is* O(log n)…

Comment: If it was a `log(size(A))` you wanted, binary search would work.  If you're trying to optimize in terms of the location of `x`, my gut says check powers of `2` until you find a value larger than `x`, then binary search in the top half, but I'm not completely clear on what you're asking.

Comment: @taylorswift I know, but I need `Θ(logd)` which means the best case is logd too, and its not correct in binary search.

Comment: @Genadi , I’m not sure if you understand what best case and worst case complexity means, *worst case* means that the algorithm can *never* take longer than O(log n) to perform this search, no matter the input. If you need an O(log n) algorithm, than every O(1) algorithm satisfies that since O(1) <~ O(log(n)).

Comment: @taylorswift its Theta(logd). please read carefully.

Comment: According to your notation, you mean to say that the average time complexity should be `logd`. The best case for any algorithm can be `O(1)` by sheer chance/coincidence

Comment: @Genadi so if I’m reading this correctly, you want an algorithm that dallies for Θ(log(n)) time no matter what, even if it already found the answer early? I don’t know why you would ever need such a thing, but you could always just use `sleep()` with the duration calculated once you find the index of the element…

Comment: @taylorswift No. I want an algorithm that in best case, would run in `Ω(logd)` and in worst case would run in `O(logd)` that is the definition of `Θ(logd)`. For example if `x` was the second element in the array, I would like to find him after 1 action and that is not the case using binary search. Got it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:  It uses Θ(log d) steps to find a range of size Θ(d), and then does a binary search in that range in another Θ(log d) steps.

```
int search(int[] array, int length, int valueToFind)
{
    int pos=0;
    int limit=min(length,1);
    while(limit < length && array[limit] < valueToFind)
    {
        pos=limit+1;
        limit = min(length, limit*2+1);
    }
    while(pos<limit)
    {
        int testpos = pos+((limit-pos)>>1);

        if (array[testpos]<valueToFind)
            pos=testpos+1;
        else
            limit=testpos;
    }
    return (pos < length && array[pos]==valueToFind ? pos : -1);
}
```

Note that the binary search I use does not exit early, and always takes Θ(log (limit-pos)) time.  Even so it's faster than other searches that do exit early, because it does only one comparison per iteration.  I describe other advantages here:

[How can I simplify this working Binary Search code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165)

Comment: That's nice! what does the operator `>>` means?

Comment: @Genadi >>1 means shift right by 1 bit.  It's the same as /2, except the division always rounds down instead of rounding toward 0, i.e., 5>>1 == 2 and -5 >>1 == -3.  The difference is not important in this application -- I could have written /2, but I'm old and I remember a time when there was a performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple `python` implementation based on the power of `2's` approach as discussed in the comments section. Please have a look:

```
def binary_search(nums,low,high,x):
  while low<=high:
    mid = (low+high)/2
    if nums[mid]==x:
      return mid+1
    elif nums[mid]>x:
      high = mid-1
    else:
      low = mid+1
  return -1

def find_index(nums,x):
  i = 1
  l = len(nums)
  while i<l:
    if nums[i-1]==x:
      return i
    elif 2*i<l and nums[2*i-1]>x:
      return binary_search(nums,i-1,2*i-1,x)
    i = 2*i
  return binary_search(nums,i/2,l-1,x)

def main():
  line = raw_input("Enter numbers: ").split()
  nums = []
  for ele in line:
    nums.append(int(ele))

  nums = sorted(nums)
  print "Sorted array: ",nums
  x = int(raw_input("Enter the element to find in sorted array: "))
  print find_index(nums, x)

main()
```

Firstly, it tries to find the target element by moving over indexes with a *power of 2*.

At any point if the current element exceeds the target element, then we do a `binary search` between the *current index(current power of 2)* and the *previous index(previous power of 2)*.

The time complexity of the searching process is `logd` on an average. Also the best case time complexity is `logd` as expected!!

Hope it is easy to understand!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If to compare different methods to find value in 1d sorted array, there is no strong winner for array sizes =<10000, each method has its own 'cons' depending on target position, array size and numpy/list option. However, for large numpy arrays(>1M) it is clear that bisect and searchsort are winners.

There are 5 methods bellow: imported bisect with verification, python loop, numba solution tal's answer at [Numpy: find first index of value fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632963/numpy-find-first-index-of-value-fast), User_Targaryen's answer above, np.searchsort with verification. All of them accept numpy/lists, except tal's answer, where the to-numpy-conversion is required for lists. Only bisect and find_index methods feels fine resisting to lists len increase.

Bellow is an example for 10K numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from timeit import timeit
import bisect
   
# bisect.bisect
def bisect_(nums,x):
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(nums, x)
    try: 
        if nums[pos] == x:
            return pos
        else:  # e.g., bisect_([1,3,4],2)
            return -1
    except:  # e.g. bisect_([1,3,4],5) 
        return -1


# python loop
def find_first(vec, item):
    for i, v in enumerate(vec):
        if item == v:
            return i
    return -1

# tal's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632963/numpy-find-first-index-of-value-fast
@jit(nopython=True)
def find_firstj(vec, item):
    """return the index of the first occurence of item in vec"""
    for i, v in enumerate(vec):
        if item == v:
            return i
    return -1

# User_Targaryen's answer above
def binary_search(nums,low,high,x):
  while low<=high:
    mid = (low+high)//2
    if nums[mid]==x:
      return mid+1
    elif nums[mid]>x:
      high = mid-1
    else:
      low = mid+1
  return -1

def find_index(nums,x):
  i = 1
  l = len(nums)
  while i<l:
    if nums[i-1]==x:
      return i
    elif 2*i<l and nums[2*i-1]>x:
      return binary_search(nums,i-1,2*i-1,x)
    i = 2*i
  return binary_search(nums,i//2,l-1,x)

# numpy searchsort
def searchsort(u, x):
    pos=np.searchsorted(u, x)
    try: 
        if u[pos] == x:
            return pos
        else:  # e.g., bisect_([1,3,4],2)
            return -1
    except:  # e.g. bisect_([1,3,4],5)
        return -1

SIZE = 10000
u = np.arange(SIZE)

# at the beginning
print('---- at the beginning ----')
x = 40

print('bisect.bisect', timeit(lambda: bisect_(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('find_first', timeit(lambda: find_first(u,x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('find_firstj', timeit(lambda: find_firstj(u,x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('find_index', timeit(lambda: find_index(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('searchsort', timeit(lambda: searchsort(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')

# in the middle
print('---- in the middle ----')
x = 5040

print('bisect.bisect', timeit(lambda: bisect.bisect(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('find_first', timeit(lambda: find_first(u,x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('find_firstj', timeit(lambda: find_firstj(u,x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('find_index', timeit(lambda: find_index(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
print('searchsort', timeit(lambda: searchsort(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')

# in the end
print('---- at the end ----')


 x = 9940
    
    print('bisect.bisect', timeit(lambda: bisect.bisect(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
    print('find_first', timeit(lambda: find_first(u,x), number=100)*10, 's')
    print('find_firstj', timeit(lambda: find_firstj(u,x), number=100)*10, 's')
    print('find_index', timeit(lambda: find_index(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
    print('searchsort', timeit(lambda: searchsort(u, x), number=100)*10, 's')
```

For 10K numpy array the result is:

```
    ---- at the beginning ----
bisect.bisect 0.009455299004912376 s
find_first 0.01455735880881548 s
find_firstj 0.023144721053540707 s
find_index 0.010857589077204466 s
searchsort 0.005023379344493151 s
---- in the middle ----
bisect.bisect 0.002835090272128582 s
find_first 1.3125479291193187 s
find_firstj 0.003973201382905245 s
find_index 0.01642579911276698 s
searchsort 0.007164010312408209 s
---- at the end ----
bisect.bisect 0.0030333898030221462 s
find_first 3.0728489509783685 s
find_firstj 0.006884939502924681 s
find_index 0.01768168993294239 s
searchsort 0.007541531231254339 s
```

For 1.5M array (x = 40/750040/1499400) the result is:

```
---- at the beginning ----
bisect.bisect 0.004126268904656172 s
find_first 0.009320289827883244 s
find_firstj 0.0005324906669557095 s
find_index 0.006837178952991962 s
searchsort 0.004959029611200094 s
---- in the middle ----
bisect.bisect 0.003964949864894152 s
find_first 166.71787671046332 s
find_firstj 0.5532677914015949 s
find_index 0.024038420524448156 s
searchsort 0.004650468472391367 s
---- at the end ----
bisect.bisect 0.0036938488483428955 s
find_first 329.8780040605925 s
find_firstj 1.570841120555997 s
find_index 0.026646379847079515 s
searchsort 0.00493861036375165 s
```

Please, copypaste to check for other sizes and options.