# sorted array, how many comparisions to find if element in

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a sorted array, and a number, how many maximum comparisons should I do to find if the number is contained in the array ?

Suppose we have a million of numbers in the array.

Comment: logn with divide and conquer or binary search

Comment: @apomene please explain how it works

Comment: to add to the previous comment, you can't say you will do log(1 million) comparisons because time complexity is rough and there is a constant to multiply with (that can be as small as 1 or less or as big as 1000 or more)

Comment: @Quade, what is the maximum comparisons number I should do?

Comment: Hint: get the median value array[N/2] and check if it is equal, larger or smaller than the target

Comment: @Damien, I uderstand that, but how calculate how many max comparisions should I do however

Comment: Max = 2*upper(log2(n)) comparaisons

Comment: @Damien, can you explain a little bit, why?

Comment: The size of the array you examine = n, n/2, n/4, ...n/(2^steps). The maximum number of steps is such that n/(2^nsteps) = 1, i.e. nsteps = log2(n)

Comment: @Damien, could you write it as an answer, please ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find element in a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810090/find-element-in-a-sorted-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the answer from @aponeme, the maximum number of comparisons is equal to

```
2*upper(log2(n))
```

The reason is that the size of the array you examine is equal to

```
n, n/2, n/4, ...n/(2^steps).
```

Then the maximum number of steps is such that

```
 n/(2^nsteps) = 1, i.e. nsteps = log2(n)
```

Comment: finally, for the concrete scenario with a n = million, the maximum number of comparisions would be log2(1000000) = 20

Answer (score 0):

With divide and Conquer or Binary search (pseudo - code):

1. Split the array in half
2. If number is bigger than max of first half work with the second half else work with first half
3. Repeat step 1 - 2 with the remaining half

Worst case scenario:  Need to divide into two arrays each of length 1 => O(logN)

Comment: I understand the algorithm, but the question is how much max comparisions should I perform

Comment: You need to add the base case when you find the element, and the worst case when the elements don't appear in the list

Comment: sorry, I am not expert in this. I have one million items 2, 4, ... 1 999 998, 2 000 000, i need to check if the element 1000 001 is in the list. How much comparations should  I do, and why?

Comment: @Siege refer to Damien last comment, I think it suffies

Comment: @apomene, please mention that answer in yours, in order I be able to mark it as answered

Comment: @Serge your question is a little bit confusing. There is no such a thing you "should do". It's up to you, prior to the algorithm design, to fix your time complexity requirements. Also we only talk about Big-O notation to estimate the performance of the algorithm, there is no fixed number

Comment: @quade: is 20 the answer, how is not a fixed number?