# what is the most efficient way to find the position of the first np.nan value?

Tags: python, numpy

consider the array `a`

```
a = np.array([3, 3, np.nan, 3, 3, np.nan])
```

I could do

```
np.isnan(a).argmax()
```

But this requires finding all `np.nan` just to find the first.
Is there a more efficient way?

---

I've been trying to figure out if I can pass a parameter to `np.argpartition` such that `np.nan` get's sorted first as opposed to last.

---

EDIT regarding [dup].
There are several reasons this question is different.

1. That question and answers addressed equality of values.  This is in regards to `isnan`.
2. Those answers all suffer from the same issue my answer faces.  Note, I provided a perfectly valid answer but highlighted it's inefficiency.  I'm looking to fix the inefficiency.

---

EDIT regarding second [dup].

Still addressing equality and question/answers are old and very possibly outdated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Numpy function to return the first index of something in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy: find first index of value fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632963/numpy-find-first-index-of-value-fast)

Comment: The 2nd dup addresses `short circuiting` alternatives.  The `isnan` part this problem does not make it unique.  But the dup is dated.

Comment: Cython/ctypes/JIT would probably be the way to go to `short circuiting` large arrays, as the second duplicate shows.

Comment: To make this fair, you need to devise a timing framework.  The short-circuiting times depend heavily on where that first `nan` occurs, while the whole array code is stable, depending only on the overall length of the array (and even then I have increase lengths above 1000 to see changes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll nominate

```
a.argmax()
```

With `@fuglede's` test array:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([np.nan if i % 10000 == 9999 else 3 for i in range(100000)])
In [2]: np.isnan(a).argmax()
Out[2]: 9999
In [3]: np.argmax(a)
Out[3]: 9999
In [4]: a.argmax()
Out[4]: 9999

In [5]: timeit a.argmax()
The slowest run took 29.94 ....
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.3 µs per loop

In [6]: timeit np.isnan(a).argmax()
The slowest run took 7.82 ...
1000 loops, best of 3: 462 µs per loop
```

I don't have `numba` installed, so can compare that.  But my speedup relative to `short` is greater than `@fuglede's` 6x.

I'm testing in Py3, which accepts `<np.nan`, while Py2 raises a runtime warning.  But the code search suggests this isn't dependent on that comparison.

`/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c` `PyArray_ArgMax` plays with axes (moving the one of interest to the end), and delegates the action to `arg_func = PyArray_DESCR(ap)->f->argmax`, a function that depends on the dtype.

In `numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src` it looks like `BOOL_argmax` short circuits, returning as soon as it encounters a `True`.

```
for (; i < n; i++) {
    if (ip[i]) {
        *max_ind = i;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And `@fname@_argmax` also short circuits on maximal `nan`. `np.nan` is 'maximal' in `argmin` as well.

```
#if @isfloat@
    if (@isnan@(mp)) {
        /* nan encountered; it's maximal */
        return 0;
    }
#endif
```

Comments from experienced `c` coders are welcomed, but it appears to me that at least for `np.nan`, a plain `argmax` will be as fast you we can get.

Playing with the `9999` in generating `a` shows that the `a.argmax` time depends on that value, consistent with short circuiting.

Comment: Now that I can think straight.  This is wonderful!  And it all comes down to `np.nan` being maximal.

Comment: Interesting! On my test setup, the plain `argmax` performs as well as the JITted search. Which I guess makes sense since apparently they're doing the same thing! I'll add the timings to the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

It might also be worth to look into `numba.jit`; without it, the vectorized version will likely beat a straight-forward pure-Python search in most scenarios, but after compiling the code, the ordinary search will take the lead, at least in my testing:

```
In [63]: a = np.array([np.nan if i % 10000 == 9999 else 3 for i in range(100000)])

In [70]: %paste
import numba

def naive(a):
        for i in range(len(a)):
                if np.isnan(a[i]):
                        return i

def short(a):
        return np.isnan(a).argmax()

@numba.jit
def naive_jit(a):
        for i in range(len(a)):
                if np.isnan(a[i]):
                        return i

@numba.jit
def short_jit(a):
        return np.isnan(a).argmax()
## -- End pasted text --

In [71]: %timeit naive(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.22 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit short(a)
The slowest run took 4.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.7 µs per loop

In [73]: %timeit naive_jit(a)
The slowest run took 6821.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.79 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit short_jit(a)
The slowest run took 395.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 144 µs per loop
```

Edit: As pointed out by @hpaulj in their answer, `numpy` actually ships with an optimized short-circuited search whose performance is comparable with the JITted search above:

```
In [26]: %paste
def plain(a):
        return a.argmax()

@numba.jit
def plain_jit(a):
        return a.argmax()
## -- End pasted text --

In [35]: %timeit naive(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.13 ms per loop

In [36]: %timeit plain(a)
The slowest run took 4.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.04 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit naive_jit(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.91 µs per loop

In [38]: %timeit plain_jit(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a pythonic approach using `itertools.takewhile()`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
sum(1 for _ in takewhile(np.isfinite, a))
```

Benchmark with generator_expression_within_`next` approach:  <sup>1</sup>

```
In [118]: a = np.repeat(a, 10000)

In [120]: %timeit next(i for i, j in enumerate(a) if np.isnan(j))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop

In [121]: %timeit sum(1 for _ in takewhile(np.isfinite, a))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
```

But still (by far) slower than numpy approach:

```
In [119]: %timeit np.isnan(a).argmax()
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.8 µs per loop
```

---

<sub>1. The problem with this approach is using  `enumerate` function. Which returns an `enumerate` object from the numpy array first (which is an iterator like object) and calling the generator function and `next` attribute of the iterator will take time.</sub>

Comment: That array is too small for these approaches to beat numpy's functions though. Try it on a larger array maybe?

Comment: @ayhan Actually it was a repeated array. I just forgot to add the related command. Here is a new one.

Comment: It's `itertools.takewhile`.

Answer (score 3):

When looking for the first match in various scenarios, we could iterate through and look for the first match and exit out on the first match rather than going/processing the entire array. So, we would have an approach using [`Python's next function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) , like so -

```
next((i for i, val in enumerate(a) if np.isnan(val)))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [192]: a = np.array([3, 3, np.nan, 3, 3, np.nan])

In [193]: next((i for i, val in enumerate(a) if np.isnan(val)))
Out[193]: 2

In [194]: a[2] = 10

In [195]: next((i for i, val in enumerate(a) if np.isnan(val)))
Out[195]: 5
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a loop with break, but this use of generator plus one `next` is equivalent.  I wonder about the speed.

Comment: For a very large array and nan near the start, an iterate till first has a chance of being faster.  But in general the compiled numpy functions will be faster even though they traverse the whole array. What's the required test suit.

Comment: I even tried to use a `deque` from `collections`.  It didn't help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40426159/901925 in the first `duplicate` presents this generator next solution.