# Why is `NaN` considered "smaller" than `-np.inf` in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

What is the reason that `NaN`'s are considered less than `-np.inf` in any comparisons involving `np.min` or `np.argmin`?

```
import numpy as np
In [73]: m = np.array([np.nan, 1., 0., -np.inf])
In [74]: n = np.array([-np.inf, 1., 0., np.nan])

# Huh??
In [75]: np.min(m)
Out[75]: nan
In [76]: np.min(n)
Out[76]: nan

# Same for np.argmin
In [77]: np.argmin(m)
Out[77]: 0
In [78]: np.argmin(n)
Out[78]: 3

# Its all false!
In [79]: np.nan < -np.inf
Out[79]: False

In [80]: np.nan > -np.inf
Out[80]: False

# OK, that seems to fix it, but its not necessarily elegant
In [81]: np.nanmin(m)
Out[81]: -inf

In [82]: np.nanargmin(m)
Out[82]: 3
```

I would guess that its probably a side effect of any comparisons with `NaN` values returning `False`, however this imho leads to some rather annoying effects when you "happen" to sometimes end up with a `NaN` value in your array. The usage of `np.nanmin` or `np.nanargmin` some feels like a quickfix that was somehow stapled on top of the existing behaviour.

Apart from that note in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin): "*NaN values are propagated, that is if at least one item is NaN, the corresponding min value will be NaN as well. To ignore NaN values (MATLAB behavior), please use nanmin.*, I haven't found anything that explains the rationale behind that behaviour. Is this wanted or a side effect of a particular internal representation of `NaN` values? And why?

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values

Comment: It is a logical behaviour: if something is not a number, it can't be compared with anything that IS a number and thus, any comparison returns false. More than that - one can argue that in most cases, `NaN` is not a desired result of some operation so it should propagate like any other exception would.

Comment: See this recent answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/41324751/901925.  `nan` is explicitly coded as `maximal` in this and related functions.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. `np.nan` is unordered with respect to any other number (itself included) without throwing an error. While it is less than, it is also greater than and not equal to any other number -- including itself. This is part of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). The implementation detail is if NaN is treated with a signal or if NaN is treated quietly. Numpy treats quietly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Dunno mentioned in a comment, it does not give much meaning to compare a NaN with a number, so this behaviour is probably ok. The IEEE 754 standard says this about comparing NaNs with numbers:

> Four mutually exclusive relations are possible: less than, equal, greater than, and unordered. The last case
>   arises when at least one operand is NaN. Every NaN shall compare unordered with everything, including
>   itself

According to the standard this:

```
# Its all false!
In [79]: np.nan < -np.inf
Out[79]: False
```

would result in an "unordered" result, so it is not true that it is belongs to the relation "less than".

Comment: The problem with this explanation is that there is no "unordered" category in Python so `np.nan < 5`, `np.nan > 5` and `np.nan == 5` cannot all evaluate to `False` but they do.  This causes all kinds of trouble if you start using `np.nan` in regular Python statements. E.g.: `min([5, np.nan])` -> `5` whereas `min([np.nan, 5])` -> `np.nan`.  I wonder why `np.nan` supports comparison and doesn't raise a TypeError like `None` does.

Answer (score 1):

So, as you might be already knowing this:-

" inf " is infinity - a value that is greater than any other value. " -inf " is, therefore, smaller than any other value remember this value is a number.

" nan " stands for Not A Number.

So, if according to your array " m,n " as you declared above and as soon as you perform " np.min() " on any of these actually what happens is as soon as " nan " is encountered the other elements are not checked or compared and the following statement is executed and the value is returned:

```
 if (@isnan@(mp)) { /* nan encountered; it's maximal */ return 0; }
```

and thus a " nan " is returned as the answer to the function!

Check this code it returns as soon as it encounter's first " nan " and its position is returned in the corresponding function

```
    In [1]: import numpy as np

    In [2]: m = np.array([1., 0., -np.inf, np.nan])

    In [3]: n = np.array([np.nan, 1., np.nan, 0.])

    In [4]: np.argmin(m)
    Out[4]: 3

    In [5]: np.argmin(n)
    Out[5]: 0
```

and the operation's such as " np.nan < -np.inf " and " np.nan > -np.inf " returns " False " because " nan " cannot be compared by any number " -inf " here and the " False " in each case of above operation is not the answer of comparison but is because of a kind of exception or the execution of the code mentioned above which is due to logical error because though infinity but it cannot be compared to a thing " nothing " with respect to a number!

and therefore if you remove all " nan " in the array and then calculate min by " np.nanmin() " you get the output as expected " -inf " here no problem arises!

So," Nan "is not smaller or greater than " inf " or " -inf " because actually it is not comparable with any of these or any number it will return " False " in comparison with any number !!

```
    In [1]: np.nan < 1
    Out[1]: False

    In [2]: np.nan > 1
    Out[2]: False
```

and so on ...............

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Technically the `numpy` c code doesn't raise an exception, it just returns.  `if (@isnan@(mp)) {
        /* nan encountered; it's maximal */
        return 0;
    }`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320568/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-position-of-the-first-np-nan-value/41324751#41324751

Comment: Yeah by raising an exception I just meant that the normal execution is stopped as soon as a " nan " is encountered I didn't knew that Thank's @hpaulj