# Why doesn't numpy NaN generate a TypeError when used in a formula?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I understand that NaN is "Not a Number", so why is it accepted into formulas without throwing any sort of exception? I understand this convenience when working with spotty data, but in a math situation why isn't it treated as zero? Instead it is like a black hole that turns everything else into NaN.

Example:

```
x = 5
y = np.NaN
z = x + y
print(z)

nan
```

Comment: Because that's how the floating point standards define NaN.  And anything done with not a number is also not a number.  (Modulo signalling versus non-signalling NaNs, but most software doesn't actually support signalling NaNs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486495/why-is-nan-considered-smaller-than-np-inf-in-numpy and links

Comment: The whole point of NaNs is that they are persistent - you only have to check the final result of any computation to see if anything went wrong along the way, rather than having to check after each step.

Answer (score 0):

As the name states NaN stands for 'Not a Number' and it is not equal to 0. So all arithmetic calculation with NaN returns NaN. In usual cases NaN  means some data is missing. As @max mentioned Numpy uses the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point for Arithmetic (IEEE 754). You could find more details here - [Numpy NA](http://www.numpy.org/NA-overview.html)