# Find (only) the first row satisfying a given condition in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with a very long column of random positive integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': np.random.randint(1, 10, size = 10000)})
```

I want to determine the index of the *first* even number in the column. One way to do this is:

```
df[df.n % 2 == 0].iloc[0]
```

but this involves a lot of operations (generate the indices `f.n % 2 == 0`, evaluate `df` on those indices and finally take the first item) and is very slow. A loop like this is much quicker:

```
for j in range(len(df)):
    if df.n.iloc[j] % 2 == 0:
        break
```

also because the first result will be probably in the first few lines.  Is there any pandas method for doing this with similar performance? Thank you.

**NOTE:** This condition (to be an even number) is just an example.  **I'm looking for a solution that works for any kind of condition on the values, i.e., for a fast one-line alternative to:**

```
df[ conditions on df.n ].iloc[0]
```

Comment: why dont you just use that loop?

Comment: Is the column sorted? If so, you can try `np.searchsorted`. If not, other than pre-sorting I don't think there is any vectorized solution for this.

Comment: @RNar: I'm learning pandas and I'd like to know how to do this within pandas @ayhan: Yes the column is sorted. But how can I specify complex conditions using `np.searchsorted`? For example, how to find the first even number?

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't work on finding even numbers. I mean you can compute the modulo for the array but that's something you want to avoid. Here are some relevant discussions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320568/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-position-of-the-first-np-nan-value), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-isnt-numpy-any-lazy-short-circuiting)

Comment: If the condition is usually satisfied in the first few rows as you say, then you could do `df.iloc[:x,df.A > 3.5].iloc[0]` to only search the first X rows.  If that misses, search next X rows, etc.  Depending on your data and choice of X that ought to be fast.  Otherwise I would probably try the numba function in one of the answers linked to by ayhan

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear, now some comments make no sense (sorry). @JohnE Yes that would be fast, but I'd like to avoid any loop in my code, if possible...

Comment: At the end of the day `conditions on df.n` is a _very_ broad ask and there are different operations based on exactly what condition is.  Regardless, it's going to be tough to get away from elementwise comparison to the Series/column.  The `.iloc[0]` or whatever else you're tacking on the end isn't the expensive part.

Comment: I think you must do either: 1) use vector logic that computes entire columns (in which case JohnE's comment is useful), or 2) loop through the first rows until your `condition(row)` is met.

Comment: Something to keep in mind when looping: when accessing a **single** value of the dataframe it is better to use `at` and `iat` instead of `loc` and `iloc`. Source: [Different ways to iterate over rows in a Pandas Dataframe — performance comparison](https://towardsdatascience.com/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-performance-comparison-dc0d5dcef8fe).

Answer (score 13):

I decided for fun to play with a few possibilities. I take a dataframe:

```
MAX = 10**7
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': range(MAX)})
```

(not random this time.) I want to find the first row for which `n >= N` for some value of `N`. I have timed the following four versions:

```
def getfirst_pandas(condition, df):
    return df[condition(df)].iloc[0]

def getfirst_iterrows_loop(condition, df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if condition(row):
            return index, row
    return None

def getfirst_for_loop(condition, df):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if condition(df.iloc[j]):
            break
    return j

def getfirst_numpy_argmax(condition, df):
    array = df.as_matrix()
    imax  = np.argmax(condition(array))
    return df.index[imax]
```

with `N` = powers of ten. Of course the numpy (optimized C) code is expected to be faster than `for` loops in python, but I wanted to see for which values of `N` python loops are still okay.

I timed the lines:

```
getfirst_pandas(lambda x: x.n >= N, df)
getfirst_iterrows_loop(lambda x: x.n >= N, df)
getfirst_for_loop(lambda x: x.n >= N, df)
getfirst_numpy_argmax(lambda x: x >= N, df.n)
```

for `N = 1, 10, 100, 1000, ...`.  This is the log-log graph of the performance:

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwFJ7.png)

The simple `for` loop is ok as long as the "first True position" is expected to be at the beginning, but then it becomes bad.  The `np.argmax` is the safest solution.

As you can see from the graph, the time for `pandas` and `argmax` remain (almost) constant, because  they always scan the whole array.  It would be perfect to have a `np` or `pandas` method which doesn't.

Comment: at least someone mentioned that complexity on for loop will depend on where does the expected result lays... and yes OP's solution is not the quickest in general as claimed by the most upvoted answer ...

Answer (score 6):

Did some timings and yes using a generator will normally give you quicker results

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': np.random.randint(1, 10, size = 10000)})

%timeit df[df.n % 2 == 0].iloc[0]
%timeit df.iloc[next(k for k,v in df.iterrows() if v.n % 2 == 0)]
%timeit df.iloc[next(t[0] for t in df.itertuples() if t.n % 2 == 0)]
```

I get:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 619 µs per loop # <-- iterrows generator
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 25 µs per loop # <--- your solution
```

However when you size it up:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': np.random.randint(1, 10, size = 1000000)})
```

The difference disappear:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 40.5 ms per loop 
10 loops, best of 3: 40.7 ms per loop # <--- iterrows
10 loops, best of 3: 56.9 ms per loop
```

Your solution is quickest, so why not use it?

```
for j in range(len(df)):
    if df.n.iloc[j] % 2 == 0:
        break
```

Comment: I agree.  I would expect that breaking out of a loop upon hitting the target row, and thus skipping the rows below, would cut of more time than finding the fastest way to iterate _all_ rows. (Especially on large dataframes)

Comment: Thank you Anton, I think I will eventually accept to write a loop in my code, which you show to be the quickest option

Comment: I think your comparison is not fair, because with your oneliners, you are accessing the row of the dataframe for which `n % 2 == 0`, whereas for the for loop, you are not doing that. For a fair comparison, you could either add `df.iloc[j]` to the three lines of code or remove the `df.iloc` around the `next` statements.

Answer (score 1):

An option to let you iterate rows and stop when you're satisfied, is to use the 
[DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), which is pandas' row iterator.

In this case you could implement it something like this:

```
def get_first_row_with(condition, df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if condition(row):
            return index, row
    return None # Condition not met on any row in entire DataFrame
```

Then, given a DataFrame, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'cats': [1,2,3,4], 
                    'dogs': [2,4,6,8]
                  }, 
                  index=['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Eve'])
```

That you can use as:

```
def some_condition(row):
    return row.cats + row.dogs >= 7

index, row = get_first_row_with(some_condition, df)

# Use results however you like, e.g.:
print('{} is the first person to have at least 7 pets.'.format(index))
print('They have {} cats and {} dogs!'.format(row.cats, row.dogs))
```

Which would output:

```
Charlie is the first person to have at least 7 pets.
They have 3 cats and 6 dogs!
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I like this solution from the style point of view. If I find no alternatives to a for loop I'll accept your answer soon

Comment: I have tested this for loop against the original pandas version, it seems to have a similar performance if the condition is met at the beginning of the array, and then it becomes less efficient (graph in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

`Zip` both the index and column, then loop over that for faster loop speed. `Zip` provides the fastest looping performance, faster than `iterrows()` or `itertuples()`.

```
for j in zip(df.index,df.n):
        if j[1] % 2 == 0:
                index_position = j[0]
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You can use `next(j for j in range(len(df)) if df.at[j, "n"] % 2 == 0)`

---

I think it is perfectly possible to do your code in a oneliner. Let's define a DataFrame to prove this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': np.random.randint(1, 10, size = 100000)})
```

First, you code gives:

```
for j in range(len(df)):
    if df.n.iloc[j] % 2 == 0:
        break
% 22.1 µs ± 1.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Converting that to a oneliner gives:

```
next(j for j in range(len(df)) if df["n"].iloc[j] % 2 == 0)
% 20.6 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

To further speed up the calculation, we can make use of `at` instead of `iloc`, as this is faster when accessing single values:

```
next(j for j in range(len(df)) if df.at[j, "n"] % 2 == 0)
% 8.88 µs ± 617 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```