# Break python loop

Tags: python, pandas

I need to stop a loop when a condition is true, I am looping thrue a pandas dataframe and I saw that the problem comes probably from the range(1,len(newdatafr)): because all the elements of this list must be 'filled'

```
for ind in range(1,len(newdatafr)):
    if newdatafr['h'][ind] > tp_2 and newdatafr['l'][ind] > sl_1:
        sl_1 = tp_2  
        print("scale up")
    elif newdatafr['h'][ind] < tp_2 and newdatafr['h'][ind] > tp_1 and newdatafr['l'][ind] > sl_1:
        sl_1 = tp_1 ## BE

    elif newdatafr['l'][ind] < sl_1: 
        print("Sortie du trade. Ouverture :"+str(open_1)+" Sortie :"+str(sl_1) )
        break
```

How can I write this in an other way ? Thank you

Comment: simply use `break`

Comment: The `break` statement in the last `elif` should stop the loop when that condition is met.

Comment: However, looping over pandas dataframes is usually the wrong way to do something. You should use its built-in filtering to get the rows up to the first one that matches the condition.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601118/find-only-the-first-row-satisfying-a-given-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/47602605 for how to find that row.

Comment: Not that simple @BemwaMalak. I tried, as it is written up.

Comment: What are `sl_1`,`tp_1`, and `tp_2`? Including (minimal) Example data (even fake data) in your question would facilitate answers. Please read [mre]. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: With `pandas dataframe` you don't "need to stop a loop". You need "not to loop". It's better that you write a new question with what you are trying to do with the loop, and someone would show you how to do it without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a break for each if statement:

```
for ind in range(1,len(newdatafr)):
    if newdatafr['h'][ind] > tp_2 and newdatafr['l'][ind] > sl_1:
        sl_1 = tp_2  
        print("scale up")
        break
    elif newdatafr['h'][ind] < tp_2 and newdatafr['h'][ind] > tp_1 and newdatafr['l'][ind] > sl_1:
        sl_1 = tp_1 ## BE
        break
    elif newdatafr['l'][ind] < sl_1: 
        print("Sortie du trade. Ouverture :"+str(open_1)+" Sortie :"+str(sl_1) )
        break
```