# What's the best way to get the index of an elemnt inside of a 2d array?

Tags: python, list

So I'm working on a project where I have a two dimensional array, and I need to find the location of an element placed on the second dimension, without knowing the index of it's first dimension.

I know that I can possibly iterate over the parts, checking to see if `list[x].index(y)` isn't a value error, but that makes my code a lot less elegant looking, and I wanted to know if there's a better way to do it, like a 2d .index method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to reinvent the wheel I believe this question has the answer you're looking for: [Is there a Numpy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/python-numpy-array-help-is-there-a-function-to-return-the-index-of-something-in/432289#432289)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,4],[4,5,6]])
item = 4
row_indices, col_indices = np.where(a == item)
```

Comment: Thanks this exactly the type of thing I wanted, because I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> v = l[x][y] if len(l) > x and len(l[x]) > y else None
>>> v is None
True
```

Comment: I don't quite get this code, how is it finding the index of the wanted value?

Comment: @Hovestar if the len of the lists are greater than the indices (i.e. `x` and `y` in this case) then it returns list[x] which is a list, and the y index from that list. Otherwise if either of the indexes are less than the length of their respective lists `None` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If length of all rows are equal, you can use this code:

```
index_2d = [item for row in list for item in row].index(y)
index_row = index_2d / ROW_LENGTH
index_col = index_2d % ROW_LENGTH
```

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't, I'm trying to make this solution work for as many possibilities as possible.