# Getting the first occurrence of a value in an N-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array), but want to reduce the array created from `mask = array == value`

```
mask = array([[[ True,  True,  True],
               [False,  True,  True]],

              [[False,  True,  True],
               [False,  True,  True]],

              [[False, False,  True],
               [False,  True,  True]]])
```

which results in

```
where(mask) = (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]),
               array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]),
               array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]))
```

and I want to reduce it to an array of the first occurrences of `True`

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1]])
```

but can't work out how to go about this from the output of `numpy.where`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If your array has 3 dimensions, shouldn't the first occurrence of True be `array([[0],[0],[0]])`? What does "an array of the first occurrences" mean?

Comment: One solution could be with `np.argmax` possibly with an axis defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's as simple as this:

```
np.argmax(mask, 2)
```

Example:

```
In [15]: %paste
mask = array([[[ True,  True,  True],
               [False,  True,  True]],

              [[False,  True,  True],
               [False,  True,  True]],

              [[False, False,  True],
               [False,  True,  True]]])

## -- End pasted text --

In [16]: np.argmax(mask, 2)
Out[16]:
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```