# Numpy - how to build a new image from 4 input images, picking the brightest pixels (max(R+G+B))

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

There are four image arrays like this:

```
image1 = np.array([
    [
      # [R  G  B]
      #  |  |  |
        [1, 2, 3], [11, 22, 55], [12, 45, 56]
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3], [56, 55, 13], [12, 45, 56]
    ],
    [
        [11, 22, 55], [56, 55, 13], [12, 45, 56]
    ],
])

image2 = np.array([
    [
        [91, 72, 33], [111, 222, 155], [212, 245, 156]
    ],
    [
        [100, 200, 113], [56, 255, 213], [112, 145, 156]
    ],
    [
        [113, 223, 255], [156, 55, 113], [212, 245, 156]
    ],
])

image3 = np.array([
    [
        [9, 2, 3], [111, 222, 255], [22, 25, 16]
    ],
    [
        [10, 20, 13], [156, 25, 23], [12, 45, 16]
    ],
    [
        [13, 23, 155], [56, 255, 13], [222, 235, 216]
    ],
])

image4 = np.array([
    [
        [29, 22, 23], [111, 222, 255], [223, 125, 216]
    ],
    [
        [210, 220, 13], [156, 252, 232], [122, 145, 216]
    ],
    [
        [123, 232, 155], [56, 255, 213], [222, 235, 216]
    ],
])
```

For each rows and columns, I want to compute the max `RGB` value of sum of `Red & Green & Blue` channel of the image arrays and use the max to build a new image array.

So after tried the following code, It got duplicate indices, because in each rows and columns the max `RGB` of three image arrays may be duplicate. But I just want to get the first match index.

```
array = np.array([image1, image2, image3, image4])
array_sum = array.sum(axis=3)
# array_sum_max_index = array_sum.argmax(axis=0)
indices = np.where(array_sum == array_sum.max(axis=0))
print(indices)
```

Output

```
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]))
```

There is a similar answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238031/getting-the-first-occurrence-of-a-value-in-an-n-dimensional-numpy-array), but it cannot resolve my question. So how to get the index when it first match.

**Edit:**

The actual number of input images is more than `32`. (Solutions involving `numpy.choose()` may not work because of this)

Comment: How does `array_sum_max_index` or `array_sum.max(axis=0)` not give you what you want?  It looks correct to me, but perhaps I am misunderstanding your goal.  `array_sum_max_index` gives `array([[1, 2, 1], [3, 3, 3], [1, 3, 2]])` telling you which image is brightest at each pixel, and `array_sum.max(axis=0)` gives you the brightest pixel taken from all the images at each location.

Comment: I want to generate a new array use the max `RGB`, but how to access `array` by `array_sum_max_index` is hard to me.

Comment: The line `array_sum_max_index = array_sum.argmax(axis=0)`, which you have commented out from some reason, gives you exactly the `(3,3)` "new image array" which you have asked for in your question.

Comment: Yes, `array_sum_max_index` is right answer, but I do not know how to use it to access `array`. So I tried `where` to get indices, which return the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
np.choose(array_sum_max_index[...,None], tuple(array))
```

**Output:**

```
array([[[ 91,  72,  33],
        [111, 222, 255],
        [212, 245, 156]],

       [[210, 220,  13],
        [156, 252, 232],
        [122, 145, 216]],

       [[113, 223, 255],
        [ 56, 255, 213],
        [222, 235, 216]]])
```

**Explanation:**

1. `array_sum_max_index` has the shape `(m,n)`, where each image is an array of shape `(m,n,3)`
2. `array` is an array of shape `(4,m,n,3)`, and each "element" of `tuple(array)` is a sub-array of shape `(m,n,3)`
3. We're trying to use `np.choose()`, passing `array_sum_max_index` as a "selector" array, and `tuple(array)` as the sequence of sub-arrays from which the selector will select from. But as you can see in the documentation for `numpy.choose()`, the "selector" array, and the sub-arrays being chosen from, **must all be broadcastable together**. Since the "selector" array `array_sum_max_index` is of shape `(m,n)`, to make it broadcastable with sub-arrays of shape `(m,n,3)`, we append an extra dimension of unit length to `array_sum_max_index`, using the expression `array_sum_max_index[...,None]`
4. This would still work if we used just `array` instead of `tuple(array)`, but the documentation for `numpy.choose()` discourages that.

Comment: Yes, but the `numpy.choose()` allows at least 0 and at most 32 array objects to pass. So the shape (x, ...) of `array`, the  `x` must be between 0 and 32.

Comment: @luneice -- Do you intend to pass more than 32 images to `np.choose()` to choose from ?

Comment: Yes, when passing more than 32 images, it got `ValueError: Need at least 0 and at most 32 array objects`.

Comment: In that case, you'll have wrap all this code into a function, and call the function multiple times. So, if you have 50 images, the first call to your function would return a new image that uses the brightest pixels from the first 32 images. The next call to your function must  pass this returned image and the remaining 18 images, to get the final image that uses the brightest pixels from all 50 images.

Comment: @luneice - I've posted a different answer that does not use `numpy.choose()`. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

(Proposing an alternative solution that does not use `numpy.choose()`, since OP has indicated that the constraint of `32` choice arrays in the case of `numpy.choose()` is an issue)

```
array = np.array([image1, image2, image3, image4])
array_sum = array.sum(axis=3)
array_sum_max_index = array_sum.argmax(axis=0)

m = 3 # Number of pixel rows
n = 3 # Number of pixel columns

array[array_sum_max_index, np.arange(m)[:,None,], np.arange(n)[None,:]]
```

**Output:**

```
array([[[ 91,  72,  33],
        [111, 222, 255],
        [212, 245, 156]],

       [[210, 220,  13],
        [156, 252, 232],
        [122, 145, 216]],

       [[113, 223, 255],
        [ 56, 255, 213],
        [222, 235, 216]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

In one line (based on @fountainhead 's answer):

```
np.take_along_axis(array, array.sum(3).argmax(0)[None, ..., None], 0)

Out[]: 
array([[[[ 91,  72,  33],
         [111, 222, 255],
         [212, 245, 156]],

        [[210, 220,  13],
         [156, 252, 232],
         [122, 145, 216]],

        [[113, 223, 255],
         [ 56, 255, 213],
         [222, 235, 216]]]])
```

Comment: Nice. And to think that all these (learning) days, I've been looking around for a real-world usecase for `numpy.take_along_axis()` !

Comment: It's made for this use-case, but it can be pretty clunky with the requirement that the array and indices have the same number of dimensions (thus the `[None, ..., None]`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`np.choose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
np.choose(array_sum_max_index, array_sum)
```

Which gives you the brightest (highest R+G+B) pixel at each location:

```
array([[196, 588, 613],
       [443, 640, 483],
       [591, 524, 673]])
```

The result is the same as `array_sum.max(axis=0)`.

Comment: I think `np.choose(array_sum_max_index, array)` is what's really required.

Comment: No, its not quite. In the `array_sum_max_index` return, which each rows and columns number represents the max `RGB` index of the `array`. So, I can generate a new array by `array_sum_max_index` return, but its hard to me.