# How to get array's col and row for specific values in python numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this :

```
a = np.array([[23,31,42],[16,22,56],[33,11,51]])
b = a.min()
print a
print b
```

So the result will be like this :

```
 [[23 31 42]
  [16 22 56]
  [33 11 51]]
 11
```

How do i get row and column of a specific value inside that array? for example :

If i want value = b where b is 11, then i'll get 2 and 1 remind that `a[2][1] = 11`

In my case, i need to get the row and column of the lowest value in my array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Numpy function to return the first index of something in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
np.where(a == a.min())
```

if `a` is an array of floats you should use instead:

```
np.where(np.allclose(a, a.min()))
```