# Efficient way to split a bytes array then convert it to string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, split

I have a numpy bytes array containing characters, followed by `b''`, followed by others characters (including weird characters which raise Unicode errors when decoding):

```
bytes = numpy.array([b'f', b'o', b'o', b'', b'b', b'a', b'd', b'\xfe', b'\x95', b'', b'\x80', b'\x04', b'\x08' b'\x06'])
```

I want to get everything before the first `b''`.

Currently my code is:

```
txt = []
for c in bytes:
    if c != b'':
        txt.append(c.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        break
txt = ''.join(txt)
```

I suppose there is a more efficient and Pythonic way to do that.

Comment: By no means a duplicate but I think you are looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/432112/2988730

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your way, it is explicit, the `for` loop is understandable by all and it isn't all that slow compared to other approaches.

Some suggestions I'd make would be to change your condition from `if c != b''` to `if c` since a non-empty byte object will be truthy and, *don't name your list `bytes`, you mask the built-in! Name it `bt` or something similar :-)

Other options include `itertools.takewhile` which will grab elements from an iterable as long as a predicate holds; your operation would look like:

```
"".join(s.decode('utf-8') for s in takewhile(bool, bt))
```

This is slightly slower but is more compact, if you're a one-liner lover this might appeal to you.

Slightly faster and also compact is using `index` along with a slice:

```
"".join(b.decode('utf-8') for b in bt[:bt.index(b'')])
```

While compact it also suffers from readability.

In short, I'd go with the for loop since readability counts as very pythonic in my eyes.

Comment: Thanks for this advices! Oh in fact the byte array was a numpy array. I like your second solution, but I benchmarked the these 3 solutions (with `ba[:np.where(ba == b'')[0][0]]` instead of `ba[:ba.index(b'')])` and it appears that the for loop solution is faster, so I choosed it.

Comment: @user2914540 oh I was unaware that it was a numpy array, maybe add the `numpy` tag and specify that `bytes` is a numpy array? There might be more efficient ways to do this in numpy.

Comment: done. Sorry, this array comes from an external library (netcdf4py) and I discovered it was a numpy array by trying to do ab.index().