# convert from one-hot encoding to class label

Tags: tensorflow

I have tensor named y, which has values from one-hot encoding over class labels:
y = [[ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.],[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.],[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  0.],
...,[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.],[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  1.],[ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]] 
so here first row has third element as '1' so it represents class label 
for that image.
Am trying to get all class labels from the given one-hot encoded array,
or the given example it should be something like this:
y = [2,0,8,...,9,2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert one hot encodings into integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497340/how-to-convert-one-hot-encodings-into-integers)

Comment: You can do that inside tensorflow graph using tf.argmax(y,1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.argmax(y)
```

Comment: Without axis = 0 it returns just one number.