# Explain numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for something similar to `list.index(value)` that works for numpy arrays. I think that `numpy.where` might do the trick, but I don't understand how it works, exactly. Could someone please explain

a) what this means

and b) whether or not it works like `list.index(value)` but with numpy arrays.

This is the article from the documentation:

> ***numpy.where(condition[, x, y])***
>
> Return elements, either from *x* or *y*,  depending on *condition*.
>   If only condition is given, `return condition.nonzero()`.
>
> **Parameters:**    condition : array_like, bool
>
> When True, yield x,  otherwise yield y.
>
> x, y : *array_like, optional*
>
> Values from which to  choose. x and y need to have the same shape as
>   condition.    **Returns:**      out : *ndarray or tuple of ndarrays*
>
> If both x and y are specified, the  output array contains elements of
>   x where condition is True, and  elements from y elsewhere. If only
>   condition is given, return the  tuple condition.nonzero(), the indices
>   where condition is True. See  also nonzero, choose
>
> *Notes*    *If x and y are given and input arrays are 1-D, where is
>   equivalent to:*    [xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in
>   zip(condition,x,y)]

Comment: Here's a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array

Comment: "a) what this means" - have you read that extract from the docs you posted here?

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, and it didn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means?:

The `numpy.where` function takes a condition as an argument and returns the indices where that condition is `true`

Is it like `list.index`?:

It is close in that it returns the indices of the array where the condition is met, while `list.index` takes a value as the argument, this can be achieved with `numpy.where` by passing `array == value` as the condition.

Example:

Using the array

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,9]])
```

and calling `numpy.where(a == 4)` returns `(array([1]), array([0]))`

calling `numpy.where(a >= 4)` returns `(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))`, two arrays of Y and X coordinates (respectively) where the condition is `true`.