# numpy argmax not working when value exceeds maximum in array

Tags: python, numpy

```
list_val = [ 30, 120, 240, 510]
num = 900

np.argmax(np.asarray(list_val) > num)
```

I want to find the position of first element in array which is greater than `num`

The output from code above is 0. However, since 900 is greater than 510, the result should be 3. How can I fix it?

--EDIT

I want a solution that works if num is 20, 200 or 900.

Comment: Simply `np.argmax(np.asarray(list_val))`, I suspect. Otherwise, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So I do not know before hand if num will be 900 or 200 or 20. Is there a solution that works for all cases?

Comment: Can you try to explain in a better/detailed way why it should be 3?

Comment: ...for example with a more "interesting" list like `[30, 10000, 500, 899, 901, 10000, 500]`

Comment: @Divakar, I want to find first element in array which is greater than `num`. will clarify in question.

Comment: 1) `want to find the position of first element in array which is greater than num`. 2) `since 900 (num) is greater than 510, the result should be 3. ` Contradictory statements. Voting to close, on grounds of being not clear.

Comment: I think you are looking for `np.where` or `np.flatnonzero`, but this is still not clear.

Comment: "Since 900 is greater than 510"… but the equation is "510 > 900", which is false…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Numpy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)  (according to the last clarification). Or simply not clear as-is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [248]: x = np.array([ 30, 120, 240, 510])
In [249]: x>200
Out[249]: array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [250]: np.argmax(_)
Out[250]: 2
In [251]: x>400
Out[251]: array([False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [252]: np.argmax(_)
Out[252]: 3
In [253]: x>600
Out[253]: array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [254]: np.argmax(_)
In [255]: np.max(__)
Out[255]: False
```

With the large threshhold, the comparison produces all `False`.  The maximum value is then `False`, and the 0th item is that.

You may have to test the `x>n` for all `False` and return a different value in that case.  This is not a universally defined behavior.

Lists have a find

```
In [261]: (x>200).tolist().index(True)
Out[261]: 2
In [262]: (x>400).tolist().index(True)
Out[262]: 3
In [263]: (x>600).tolist().index(True)
...
ValueError: True is not in list
```

The `string` `find` returns a `-1` if the value is not found.

---

```
In [266]: def foo(test):
     ...:     if not test.any():
     ...:         return -1
     ...:     return np.argmax(test)
     ...: 
In [267]: foo(x>200)
Out[267]: 2
In [268]: foo(x>400)
Out[268]: 3
In [269]: foo(x>600)
Out[269]: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of `argmax()`:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([30, 120, 240, 510])
np.argmax(a)
```

Out:

```
3
```

Your code evals `0` is because `np.asarray(list_val) > num` is an array whose entries all `False` i.e. no element is greater than `num`, so `np.argmax` takes `False` as 0 and throws a zero as `argmax`.

If you'd like to have a threshold, try `np.argmax(a[a<num])`:

```
num = 900
np.argmax(a[a<num])
```

Out:

```
3
```

Or:

```
a=np.array([30, 120, 240, 510])
num = 200
np.argmax(a[a<num])
```

Out:

```
1
```

This will raise `ValueError` instead of `0` if nothing meets the threshold:

```
num = 20
np.argmax(a[a<num])
```

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-d373c6004311> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 a=np.array([30, 120, 240, 510])
      2 num = 20
----> 3 np.argmax(a[a<num])

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     55 
     56     try:
---> 57         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58     except TypeError:
     59         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```