# How to find the index of array by a value which is an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to find the index of a numpy array by value. The value however is also an array. In other words, it's a multi dimensional array.

For example:

```
a = [
[[1, 0], [0, 2], [3, 3]], 
[[1, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0]], 
[[4, 0], [2, 3], [3, 0]]
]
```

I want to find the index of `[[1, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0]]`, which is `1`. Basically, I want to find the element in the array which matches the array pattern that I have.

How can I do this using numpy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Numpy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

Comment: It isn't a perfect duplicate, so I'm not very inclined to close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.flatnonzero` in conjunction with broadcasted comparison:

```
a

array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 0]],

       [[4, 0],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 0]]])

np.flatnonzero((a == [[1, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0]]).all(1).all(1))
array([1])
```

Borrowing from the other answer, you could pass multiple axes to `all`:

```
np.flatnonzero((a == [[1, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0]]).all((1, 2)))
array([1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.all` and `np.where`:

```
 np.where(np.all(a==template, axis=(1,2)))[0][0]
 # 1
```