# Everytime I run this code it says that numpy.ndarray has not attribute 'index'

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code it returns that the `numpy.ndarray` object has no attributes. I'm trying to write a function that in case the number given is in the array will return with the position of that number in the array.

```py
a = np.c_[np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
x = int(input('Type a number'))

def findelement(x, a):
    if x in a:
        print (a.index(x))    
    else:
        print (-1)

print(findelement(x, a))
```

Comment: Well, yeah. NumPy arrays don't have an `index` method. Why are you trying to use list code with arrays?

Comment: That's because a NumPy array doesn't have a method called `index`. Maybe you were thinking of a plain Python list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

Comment: Numpy arrays don't have a `.index` attribute. Perhaps you were thinking of pandas dataframes? To find a list of attributes of an object, you can always try `dir(object)` to see these attributes. For example, try `dir(np.array([1,2,3]))` to see a list of available attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `np.where` instead of `list.index`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.c_[np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]

x = int(input('Type a number: '))

def findelement(x, a):
    if x in a:
        print(np.where(a == x)[0][0])    
    else:
        print(-1)

print(findelement(x, a))
```

Result:

```
Type a number: 3
2
None
```

> Note  `np.where` returns the indices of elements in an input array where
>   the given condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `np.where` and `np.argwhere`.