# Get the indexes of a numpy array inside another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to get the indexes of a numpy array inside another numpy array, for example , I have

```py
 y = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8])
 x = np.array([3, 1, 8])
```

x is included in y, so what I would want to get is the indexes `idx` of the x array  on the y array, in the same order, so here it would be `idx = array([2, 0, 5])` so that we have `np.array_equal(y[idx] ,x)` yields `True`, 
I tried to use `np.argwhere(np.in1d(y,x))` , but obviously I don't get the same order , I know I can always use list comprehension `idx = [ list(y).index(el) for el in x]`, but I prefer to use numpy.
Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

```
>>> t = array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3, 8, 8])
>>> nonzero(t == 8)
(array([6, 8, 9]),)
>>> nonzero(t == 8)[0][0]
6
```

So adapting for your case:

```
lst=[]
for item in x:
    lst.append( list(nonzero(y == item)) )
```

Comment: yeah you're right, but I'd prefer to avoid for loops as it slows down the process

Comment: You probably will have to use a loop somewhere, you could compress it into one line though through comprehension