# In 1D array 'a' find indexes of 'a' at which 'a'='b', where 'b' are random values of 'a'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is my first attempt to use Python. I would appreciate any advice on how to post process data using Python.

I have a 2D array with two columns that consists of numbers: `a` and `c`. In addition, I have 1D array `b` that consists of some specific (and exact) values of `a`. What I want to do is to find `c` values at which `a == b`. My approach is to find indexes of `a` where `a == b` and then use `b[a_indexes]`. I fail at finding indexes.

```
    'a'    'c'  
     1     20   
     40    70
     83    67
     1054  90

     'b'
      40
      1054
```

Desired output:

```
40 70
1054 90
```

I tried:

```
a_indexes = a.index(b)
```

But it does not work.

I have this error:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: are values in 'a' by any chance unique?

Comment: It's better, if you have added inputs in question.

Comment: Hey! thanks for answers, I added an example.

Comment: I mean, code used to create your 2d numpy array/your numpy array itself.

Comment: I import this data and trying to post process it in Python. So it is given by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to do something like

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 20],  [40, 70], [83, 67], [1054,90]])
b = np.array([40, 1054])

output = []
for value in b:
    a_indexes = np.where(arr == value)
    for a_index in a_indexes[0]: # we look where the value was found along first dimension
        output.append(arr[a_index])
# output should be [array([40, 70]), array([1054, 90])]
print(output)
```

For more information on indexing check [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array) or https://thispointer.com/find-the-index-of-a-value-in-numpy-array/

Note that if you have column names, probably you are not dealing with pure numpy arrays, but maybe pandas dataframe or something else.

Comment: "DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future." no success

Comment: I expanded my answer

Comment: `a_indexes = np.where(arr[:,0] == value)` to just include first column.