# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array such as this:

```
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1
  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
```

I am trying to access the index of an elements equaling -1 in a np array. I found NumPy has an equivalent to list.index but I keep getting an attribute error:  'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'

I saw here [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array) that I should use where, however when I try the following I get the above error:

```
for pred in outlier_preds:
    if pred == -1:
        index = where(predictions)
```

I also tried:

```
for pred in outlier_preds:
    if pred == -1:
        index = outlier_preds.where(pred == -1)
        outlier_indecies.append(index)
```

And:

```
for pred in outlier_preds:
    if pred == -1:
        index = outlier_preds.where(preds)
```

There is obviously an attribute where() but for some reason it isn't working, I guess the way I am trying to use it?

Obviously I can get around it by converting it to a list but I would like to know how to use where correctly if possible

Comment: There is a numpy function with that name, but not a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs of [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) - the function returns the indexes where the condition within the function is True.

**Example:**

```
>>> np.where(outlier_preds == -1)
(array([ 35,  59, 117, 118, 119, 126, 128, 141, 143, 144, 145, 146, 149,
        150, 151, 152, 153, 155, 156, 162, 175, 176, 184, 192, 201, 202,
        203, 204, 205, 214, 217, 218], dtype=int64),)
>>> np.where(outlier_preds == -1)[0][0] #First element only
35
```