# How do i code for find coordinates in 2d matrix?

Tags: python

If the 3x4 matrix is shown below,

`a=[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]`

I want to find 7 and draw the coordinate value (2,3) into a variable.

Do you have a built-in function?

In matlab, `[row, col] = find(a==7)`, and result is row=2,col=3.

I'm curious about how Python works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After initializing the value of the matrix value you want,

```
val = 7
```

here is a nice one-liner:

```
array = [(ix,iy) for ix, row in enumerate(a) for iy, i in enumerate(row) if i == val]
```

**Output** of `print(array)`:

```
[(1, 2)]
```

Note the one-liner will catch all instances of the number 7 in a matrix, not just one. Also note the indexes start at 0, so row 2 will be displayed as 1 and column 3 will be displayed as 2. If, say, you have more than one instance of 7 in a row and want the actual row and column numbers (not starting at 0), this may be helpful:

```
a=[[1,7,7,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,7]]
val = 7
array = [(ix+1,iy+1) for ix, row in enumerate(a) for iy, i in enumerate(row) if i == val]
print(array)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it similar to `Matlab` you would have to use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]

a = np.array(a)

rows, cols = np.where(a == 7)

print(rows[0], cols[0])
```

It can find all `7` in matrix so it returns `rows`, `cols` as lists.

And it counts rows/cols starting at `0` so you may have to add `+1` to get the same results as `matlab`

Comment: thank you very much!
I wonder why using np.array.
Is is different with just python array?

Comment: Python is general-purpose language and it has only normal list which doesn't have functions like array in specialized matlab. To do it similar to `matlab` you have to use `numpy`.

Answer (score -1):

I would use numpy's [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.htm) function. Here's [another post that displays it's use nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array). I'd apply it to your use case like so:

```
 import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 100, 6],[100, 8, 9]])
positions = np.where(arr == 100)
# positions = (array([1, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 0], dtype=int64))
positions = [tuple(cor.item() for cor in pos) for pos in positions]
# positions = [(1, 2), (1, 0)]
```

Note that this solution allows for the possibly that the desired pattern might occur more than once.