# finding the position of an element within a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to ask a question about finding the position of an element within an array in Python's numpy package.

I am using Jupyter Notebook for Python 3 and have the following code illustrated below:

```
concentration_list = array([172.95, 173.97, 208.95])
```

and I want to write a block of code that would be able to return the position of an element within the array.

For this purpose, I wanted to use `172.95` to demonstrate.

Initially, I attempted to use `.index()`, passing in `172.95` inside the parentheses but this did not work as numpy does not recognise the `.index()` method -

```
concentration_position = concentration_list.index(172.95)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

The Sci.py documentation did not mention anything about such a method being available when I accessed the site.

Is there any function available (that I may not have discovered) to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the  `where` function from the `numpy` library

```
import numpy as np

concentration_list = np.array([172.95, 173.97, 208.95])
number = 172.95

print(np.where(concentration_list == number)[0])


Output : [0]
```

Comment: From the docs for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where(...)` for this purpose e.g.

```py
import numpy as np

concentration_list = np.array([172.95, 173.97, 208.95])

index=np.ravel(np.asarray(concentration_list==172.95).nonzero())

print(index)

#outputs (array of all indexes matching the condition):

>> [0]
```

Comment: From the docs for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._

Comment: Tweaked! Cheers!