# is there a posibillity to find out the position on an element in an array with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, position

If i've got an numpy array like for example [1, 7, 10, 5, 2, 9, 8], is there a posibillity to find out on which position in this array is one special Element, for example the 5?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flag=0
demo = [1, 7, 10, 5, 2, 9, 8]
for x in demo:
    if x==5:
        print('Position',flag+1)
    flag+=1
```

This might just work although there are many other ways but this one simple to digest

Answer (score 0):

```
i= numpy.where(vector == 5)
```

By numpy library you can do this without loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
x=[1, 7, 10, 5, 2, 9, 8]
print(x.index(5))
```

It returns the first occurrence of the specified value.

Comment: Question was asking for a method using `numpy`, not standard library.