# How to find regions of ones surrounded by zeros in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like

```py
arr1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1])
arr2 = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

`0`-water
`1`-land
I want to find the index of the island with water surrounding it.
For example in the `arr1` water starts at index `4` and island index `6` to `8` is surrounded by two water strip. So the answer for `arr1` is

```
[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

but in the second case there is not land surrounded by water, so no output.

Comment: Just write a simple scanning search algorithm in O(n). No need for numpy.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array

Comment: `np.diff()` is useful for finding changes of values.

Comment: Does the array always start and finish with 1? If not what's the required behaviour if the start or end is 0? If both are zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach pads the array with a one at the start and the end. And calculates the differences: these are `-1` when going from water to land, `1` when going from land to water, and `0` everywhere else.

The following code constructs a series of test cases and visualizes the function. It can serve as a test bed for different definitions of the desired outcome.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

def find_islands(arr):
    d = np.diff(np.pad(arr, pad_width=(1, 1), constant_values=1))
    land_starts, = np.nonzero(d == 1)
    land_ends, = np.nonzero(d == -1)
    if len(land_starts) > 1 and len(land_ends) > 1:
        return np.arange(arr.size)[land_ends[0]: land_starts[-1]]
    else:
        return None

def show_array(arr, y, color0='skyblue', color1='limegreen'):
    if arr is not None:
        plt.imshow(arr[np.newaxis, :], cmap=ListedColormap([color0, color1]), vmin=0, vmax=1,
                   extent=[0, arr.size, y, y + 2])

def mark_array(arr, y, color0='none', color1='crimson'):
    if arr is not None:
        pix = np.zeros(arr[-1] + 1)
        pix[arr] = 1
        show_array(pix, y, color0, color1)

tests = [np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]),
         np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
         np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
         np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
         np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]),
         np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]),
         np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
         np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]),
         np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]),
         np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]),
         np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])]
for arr, y in zip(tests, range(0, 1000, 5)):
    show_array(arr, y + 2)
    result = find_islands(arr)
    mark_array(result, y)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale()
ax.axis('auto')
plt.show()
```

[image: test plot]

Comment: I relly appriciate