# Finding the indexes of a string array in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, format

What would be a numpy function that goes through array `a` and then output the indexes where values of array `b` is allocated.

Code:

```
a = np.array(["BTCUSD", "ETHUSDC", "BBB", "ETHUSD", "cow"])
b=  np.array(["BTCUSD", "ETHUSD"])
```

Expected output:

```
Indexes: 0, 3
```

Comment: What does `a=='hello' do?

Answer (score 0):

```py
phraseIndex = np.where(a == phrase)
```

[w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_search.asp)

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array)

[NumPy Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)