# How to get only the index in numpy.where instead of a tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of strings `arr` in which I want to search for elements and get the index of element. Numpy has a method `where` to search element and return index in a tuple form.

```
arr = numpy.array(["string1","string2","string3"])
print(numpy.where(arr == "string1")
```

It prints:

```
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

But I only want the index number `0`.

I tried this:

```
i = numpy.where(arr == "string1")
print("idx = {}".format(i[0]))
```

which has output:

```
i = [0]
```

Is there any way to get the index number without using replace or slicing method?

Comment: I find this helpful [Extract the index from ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994923/15633731)

Comment: What's the problem with `np.where(arr)[0][0]`?

Comment: `np.where(arr)[0][0]` is 0 and print 0 on my machine (which is the good index)...

Comment: @lokp I have no idea how you got such a result. I guess the answer by joanis will clarify something for you.

Comment: @dankal444 careful here, you said `np.where(arr)` in your comment above, but that's going to return every index in `arr` which is non-zero/non-false, i.e., all indices (`(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),)`. You need `np.where(arr == "string1")[0][0]`, not `np.where(arr)[0][0]`

Comment: @dankal444 yes you are right

Comment: @joanis yes, sure. I just wanted to write `np.where(arrayName)[0][0]` to show how to get the index instead of tuple. Should have choosen different name for input array - did not notice its the same in OP question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Use:

```
try:
    i = numpy.where(arr == "string1")[0][0]
except IndexError:
    # handle the case where "string1" was not found in arr
```

or

```
indices = list(numpy.where(arr == "string1")[0])
```

##### Details

Finding elements in NumPy arrays is not intuitive the first time you try to do it.

Let's decompose the operation:

```
>>> arr = numpy.array(["string1","string2","string3"])
>>> arr == "string1"
array([ True, False, False])
```

Notice how just doing `arr == "string1"` is already doing the search: it's returning an array of booleans of the same shape as `arr` telling us where the condition is true.

Then, you're using `numpy.where` which, when used with only one parameter (the condition), returns where its input is non-zero. With booleans, that means non false.

```
>>> numpy.where(numpy.array([ True, False, False]))
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
>>> numpy.where(arr == "string1")
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

It's not quite clear to my where this gives you a tuple of arrays for a 1-D input, but when you use this syntax with a 2-d input, it makes more sense.

In any case, what you're getting here is a tuple containing a list of indices where the condition matches. Notice it has to be a list, because you might have multiple matches.

For your code, you want `numpy.where(arr == "string1")[0][0]`, because you know `"string1"` occurs in the list, but the inner list may also contain zero or more than one values, depending on how many times the string is found.

```
>>> arr2 = numpy.array(["string1","string2","string3","string1", "string3"])
>>> numpy.where(arr2 == "foo")
(array([], dtype=int64),)
>>> numpy.where(arr2 == "string3")
(array([2, 4], dtype=int64),)
```

So when you want to use these indices, you should simply treat `numpy.where(arr == "string1")[0]` as a list (it's really a 1-D array, though) and continue from there.

Now, just using `numpy.where(arr == "some string")[0][0]` is risky, because it will throw an `IndexError` exception if the string is not found in `arr`. If you really want to do that, do it in a try/except block.

If you need the list of indices as a Python list, you can do this:

```
indices = list(numpy.where(arr == "string1")[0])
```

Comment: Having the option to let np.where() return n indices (and setting n=1) would be incredibly useful. Now it looks ugly...